# PHP, include absolute path from home directory

Tags: php

In html, the backslash(/) at the beginning tells the system to start looking from the home directory. For example,

```
<a href="/folder1/example.css">Link</a>
<img scr="/images/example.jpg">Image />
```

To repeat, the / tells the system to look from the home directory.

Is there a way to do same thing in PHP as in?

```php
<?php include '/header.php'; ?>
```

The php code below will only look up header.php one directory below the current directory. Please comment if my question is not clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: You're link is probably wrong and your code is not showing. Please edit.

Comment: I cant find a button to edit my question. how can I edit my question?

Comment: @rattanak: I've done that for you

Comment: No, `/` is *not* the home directory. To repeat, the `/` is not telling the system to look for the home directory.

Comment: @zerkms Apparently, you haven't.  I would do it myself, but I don't have that privilege yet.

Comment: @Daedalus: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11961866/revisions -- if you see here that you find that I have changed formatting for you

Comment: @zerkms I looked at the revision, I did refresh several times to make sure; you never altered the display of the php code.

Comment: @Daedalus: I've missed php, but I did altered the display of html

Comment: @zerkms Thanks a lot. I am relatively new to stackoverflow. I find the formatting is confusing to me. Any help please.

Answer (score 4):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` quite probably refers to the directory you are trying to access.

Comment: it will not help in his case. He needs to define that path in a global config file, whatever it is. Example $wwwroot = '/' and then use it everywhere like this <a href="<?=$wwwroot?>/folder1/example.css">Link</a>

Comment: On my linux server, it is returning: /www

Answer (score 0):

<del>If you mean "home" as in the web root, then $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] should do the trick.</del>

As pointed out elsewhere, that may not return what you expect. The code below should still work though.

A lot of people define an ABSPATH constant. If your app is always routed through index.php, then the following might be easier to implement at the top of index.php

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );

// this can then be called from any where
require_once(ABSPATH . "includes/header.php");

// or in your example
<img src="<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>images/example.jpg" />
```

Comment: What is dirname(__FILE__)? is it to be replaced by the path I defining as the root?

Comment: It's a magic constant. It refers to the actual file. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php